# oracle sql query generating some unexected resutls

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an sql query in which I have table named `attan` for the attendance and column named
`S_TIME` in which I stored in time and out time with a setting a flag of in with `I` and for `O`

Now I am trying to get in time as well as out time using the flag. I have written a query but result from this query are making some wrong sense.

Here is my query

```
SELECT X.AC_NO, X.IN_TIME, Y.OUT_TIME, X.S_DTE, X.CHK_IN, Y.CHK_OUT
  FROM (SELECT A.AC_NO, A.S_TIME IN_TIME, A.AC_CHECKTYPE CHK_IN, A.S_DTE
          FROM ATTN A
         WHERE A.AC_CHECKTYPE = 'I' AND A.S_DTE = :P_DTE) X,
       (SELECT B.AC_NO, B.S_TIME OUT_TIME, B.AC_CHECKTYPE CHK_OUT
          FROM ATTN B
         WHERE B.AC_CHECKTYPE = 'O' AND B.S_DTE = :P_DTE) Y
 WHERE X.AC_NO = Y.AC_NO(+)
```

Through this query I always get the number of records of the employees who are in and only get 2 number of reocrds with out time.

Whereas in table there are 234 number of emps who are in and 256 are out but results don't match the data.

Please any one help me if any problem in my query.

Comment: Could you post a small data sample that this query works incorrectly on? Could you also post the expected output and the actual output of your query for that data sample?

Comment: Sir As I described in second line data is retriving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUGGESTION:

1. Run the subselects and see if you're getting all the rows you expect, with and without the "A.S_DTE = :P_DTE" date filter:

   `SELECT A.AC_NO, A.S_TIME IN_TIME, A.AC_CHECKTYPE CHK_IN, A.S_DTE
    FROM ATTN A
    WHERE A.AC_CHECKTYPE = 'I' AND A.S_DTE = :P_DTE`
2. My first guess is that maybe you have a datetime, and unless the hours/minutes/seconds match *exactly*, you won't get the row.  You can use to_char() to have just the "date" portion in your "from":

   http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:204714700346328550
3. In any case, seeing what rows you do (and don't) get in the subqueries should show you what's wrong with the complete query.

Please post back what you find!

Comment: Yes Sir I already check the both sub queries and data is retrieving Sir I have only date portion in S_dte column.time portion is only in s_time